# Confusing result in calculating normals

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d

I am working on a 3D graphics engine and one thing that is important is defining a "front" face and a "back" face of triangles that I define.

A convention is, that the vertices of the triangle should be arranged in a way, that is counter-clockwise to the observer. That way, I can calculate a normal vector, which will always point toward the observer, as long as I arrange the points counter-clockwise from that observer's view.

Here is an example:

Let's say in a 3D coordinate system, an observer (Let's just say the observer is located at (0,0,1) is looking down in the direction (0,0,-1) at a triangle with the vertices (0,0,0), (0,1,0) and (1,0,0).

Now if I wanted that triangle's front face facing the observer, I would have to arrange the vertices in an order, that is counter-clockwise to the observer. For example:

a = (0,0,0)
b = (1,0,0)
c = (0,1,0)

Then I can calculate the normal vector like this using the cross product:

[normal calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Y5O.gif)

The resulting normal vector is (0,0,1). In this case, this normal vector is directly opposed to the viewing direction of (0,0,-1), which makes sense, since the observer is looking down at the front face of the triangle and the normal vector faces outward of the front face of that triangle.

My problem is with this scenario:

The observer is located at (2,4,3) and is looking down at a direction of (0,-1,0).

The vertices of the triangle are (0,-1,0), (1,-1,1) and (1,-1,0).

Here is a small sketch:

[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8rfj.png)

Now, from this view, I arrange the vertices in a counter-clockwise way, like this:

a = (0,-1,0)
b = (1,-1,0)
c = (1,-1,1)

I would expect the normal vector, similar to the previous example, to be directly opposed to the viewing direction, since the view plane and the plane defined by the triangle are parallel, but the resulting normal vector (calculated the same way as in the previous example) is (0,-1,0)! That's the exact same as the viewing direction! Which means the camera is actually looking at the back side of the triangle.

Why?

I arranged the vertices in a manner, that is counter-clockwise to the observer, so why is the observer facing the backside and not the front side?

Comment: This is a left-handed coordinate system, so the normal vectors are opposite the direction you would expect. Also, the order $a, b, c$ is clockwise in the first example, so it is wrong. If you did $c, b, a$ instead, the normal would be pointing away from you.

Comment: I would try $x$ pointing out of the screen, $y$ pointing right, and $z$ pointing up.

Comment: @JoshuaWang Thank you for your answer! I didn't take into account left and right handed systems

Comment: Yeah, 3d is confusing :b. If you want to implement a perspective camera system instead of just orthographic, you'll have a whole new problem defining what the normal is.

Comment: @JoshuaWang I am actually implementing a perspective camera. I only need to calculate the normals to determine which triangles are not facing the camera, so they're not rendered.

Comment: @JoshuaWang It's just a wireframe renderer. Don't know if I will (or want) to dive into shading/lighting

Comment: Are you calculating a dot product or something to determinine if the face should be occluded?

Comment: @JoshuaWang You mean ambient occlusion? Like I said, it's just a wireframe renderer. Just a bunch of purely white lines on a black background until now.

Comment: What I mean is, how are you deciding if the face is facing away from you or not?

Comment: @JoshuaWang Don't roll your eyes, because I didn't look up an actual algorithm for this. I just kinda came up with my own (possibly horrible way) of doing this. Bascially, in perspective transformation you have a view plane on which each vertex of any triangle inside a mesh is projected onto to calculate the pixel coordinates. Now, how do I determine whether the triangle is facing away? I define a straight line with the starting point in the middle of the triangle and the directional vector being the normal of the triangle. I also

Comment: describe the viewing plane using the camera point as a starting point and 2 directional vectors, calculated from the camera parameters. This way of representation includes a variable scalar weigth for the directional vector or vectors for any line or plane. I then calculate the intersection of the plane and the line by creating an equation with the plane on one side and the line on the other side. This leaves me with a linear-equation system, which can be resolved (using inverse matrix) and leaves me with a result for each scalar weigth of

Comment: the directional vectors. If I plug those scalars into the previous equation, both sides of that equation will describe the intersection point of those 2 objects, one of them by starting from the position of the camera and going a certain amount of the 2 directional vectors and the other one starting at the middle of the triangle and going a certain amount of the directional vector (which is the normal). If I look at the scalar which weights the directional vector of the

Comment: line (the triangle normal) I look if it is positive or negative. If it is positive, it means it is opposing the view direction, which means it should be rendered, If it is negative, it means the camera faces the backside, so it is not rendered.

Comment: Sorry if my answer seems confusing, I learned all the terminology in german and don't know if I used the correct english counterparts

Comment: This isn't implemented yet, that's why I asked about the confusing normal result first, I don't know if this will actually work, but if I haven't overlooked something else, it should, right?

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it should work. I asked because the naive way of just calculating the dot product of the normal with the camera direction and seeing if it's negative (i.e, seeing if the angle of the face to the camera plane is acute) only works in orthographic, not perspective.

Comment: @JoshuaWang Thank YOU for looking at my problem!